# Send mail with some delay time in odoo11

Tags: email, templates, odoo, job-scheduling, odoo-11

I have to send a mail when stage changes with a delay of some specific time. For example, in my case, I have to send mail after 10 minutes of stage changes. The time should be configurable.
I have try to achieve this by making force parameter to false as below:-

```
self.env['mail.template'].browse(template.id).send_mail(self.id, force_send=False)
```

And after that i have changed time intervals of "Mail: Email Queue Manager" template in scheduled action as per my requirement. In this case arises that When i send 2 mails lets say first mail on 11:30 and second mail on 11:33 and scheduled action will be performed on 11:35. So it sends both mails on 11:35 instead of sending mails on 11:35 and 11:38 respectively if i scheduled it at every 5 minutes after stage changes.
So how can i achieve this?

Comment: AFAIK that's not possible with Odoo default functionality.

Comment: thanks for the response but how can we achieve with customisation also. Is there any way? let me know if there is any custom solution.

Comment: Many roads lead to Rome ;-) You can try to add some own queuing functionality or just change `mail.mail` by adding a field "dont sent before" and change Odoo's `mail.server` cronjob. or or or ...

Answer (score 1):

You may pass the send mail function to a new thread with execution time 5 minutes

Imagine that the Odoo project is running in a main thread and you are gonna send the mail in a second thread

```py
import threading 
import time
  
def odoo_project():
    for x in range(0,11):
            print(x)
            time.sleep(1)

def mail_sender(): 
    for x in range(100,103):
            print(x)
            time.sleep(5)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=odoo_project)  
t2 = threading.Thread(target=mail_sender)  
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

This will output

```
0
100
1
2
3
4
101
5
6
7
8
9
102
10
```

which means the Odoo project will continue working while the mail thread is gonna send the mail after 5 minutes -replace 5 with 5 * 60 in the example-

Also it would be a better design if you did a config field that you type the delay value in it instead of hard-coding the 5 minutes in the code in case you wanted future updates